# CLLocationManager delegate methods not called with iBeacon Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ibeacon

I am attempting to create a demo app that monitors iBeacons. I am using a table view and a custom cell that is a location manager delegate.

I am using Estimote's beacon simulator that allows using an iPhone as a beacon. When the app runs, the location manager's `didRangeBeacons:`method is called but none of the other delegate methods are called. I have used the Estimote app to ensure that my iPhone is definitely broadcasting.

`startMonitoringBeacon:` is called when the UITableViewCell is created in the parent view controller.

Here is my custom UITableViewCell

```
@implementation PTBeaconTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.locationMgr = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationMgr.delegate = self;
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
    for(CLBeacon* beacon in beacons) {
        if([_beacon isEqualToBeacon:beacon]) {
            NSString* foundMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Found: %@", _beacon.uuid.UUIDString];
            [self.detailLabel setText:foundMsg];
        }
    }
}

-(NSString*)getTimeStamp {
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
    return [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSString* message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Exited at %@", [self getTimeStamp]];
    [self.statusLabel setText:message];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSString* message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Region Entered at %@", [self getTimeStamp]];
    [self.statusLabel setText:message];
}

-(CLBeaconRegion*)getRegionForBeacon:(PTBeacon*)beacon {
    return [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:_beacon.uuid major:_beacon.major minor:_beacon.minor identifier:_beacon.name];
}

-(void)startMonitoringBeacon:(PTBeacon*)beacon {
    CLBeaconRegion* region = [self getRegionForBeacon:beacon];
    [self.locationMgr startMonitoringForRegion:region];
    [self.locationMgr startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
    [self.statusLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Monitoring began at %@", [self getTimeStamp]]];
}

-(void)stopMonitoringBeacon:(PTBeacon*)beacon {
    CLBeaconRegion* region = [self getRegionForBeacon:beacon];
    [self.locationMgr stopMonitoringForRegion:region];
    [self.locationMgr stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
    [self.statusLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Monitoring stopped at %@", [self getTimeStamp]]];
}

@end
```

Any suggestions on what may be missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to start the broadcasting of Estimote app when your application is already on and monitoring. It would simulate you entering the region that should trigger `didEnterRegion`. Stopping the broadcasting on the other hand triggers `didExitRegion`.

Stupid question but try to `println()` a log message inside those method. I see you just update a label, but is it properly connected in your Storyboard/xib?

Comment: Yes, the cell is rendering properly and I've set breakpoints at the location you mentioned and they are never hit

Comment: Starting the estimote app after starting the demo app helps and I am getting notified on entering a region.

Answer (score 1):

First of all why are you putting location manager handling in `UITableViewCell`. It should be in some view controller rather. Cells are used/reused every now and then. Secondly, during region monitoring/ranging, not getting call backs on some of the delegates like `locationManager:monitoringDidFailForRegion:withError:` & `locationManager:didFailWithError:` is alright. Please go through this nicely put up [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/66584/ios7-ibeacons-tutorial).